# how do i query firebase based on age but get the ID as well?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

this is my database. how do i query them base on age (less then or more then) but for just 1 user (example = **one** random user based on age less then ##) and then get the ID of user result ?

Comment: Your `userAge` appears to be a string.  You're going to have a hard time sorting that numerically, since strings sort differently than number types.  You should always store numeric data as number types.

Comment: Firebase queries can only order/filter on one property. You *could* add an artificial property that combines the UID and age, like `"uid_age": "U8olCcffleXjXKk6IT7pJu0pBA3_021"` and then order/filter on that. Note the `0` prefix is to ensure you can filter on ages up to `999`. But I would seriously consider what you'll gain by doing the filtering in this use-case, over simply read the one document by its key, and then checking client-side for the `userAge` value.